# Car is sluggish, jerking, and idles rough

Tags: fuel-system, vw, troubleshooting, air-filter, fuel-filter

I have a VW Polo Classic, 1.6L.

Just recently it started to be slightly jerky when in idle and whilst driving. There is also a loss of power, a strong fuel smell, and sounding slightly like a VW Beetle.

I am thinking it is either:

1. Spark plugs
2. Fuel Filter
3. Fuel Pump

Can anyone lend some advice on how to determine the issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Other possible sources:

- Vacuum Leak
- Other Ignition item (Plug Wires, Distributer, etc.)
- Really poor fuel
- Air Filter Blocked
- Exhaust Blockage

I would start with the spark plugs.  Take them out and see if they can give any indication as to the true problem. See [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/642/how-do-i-know-when-to-change-my-spark-plug/649#649) for more info (While you have them out, replace them if you need to).  Then start checking/replacing easy items like:  Looking for disconnected hoses, checking the air filter, etc.

Comment: Thank you @jzd for the answer. I will start with the spark plugs and revert.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem with my Polo 1.6 2008 model the HT leads come with a metal surround that arc's against the cylinder head remove the metal surround and it resolved me problem

Answer (score 1):

MlAfter a lot of investigation, we found mine was caused by a wire that was coming away inside the distributor cap

Answer (score 0):

[IAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_air_control_actuator), if it's fuel injected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that sounds exactly like what my car had. Everything in your description matches what I was worrying about and at the shop they told me it was a faulty oxygen sensor. The repair will cost me $300 dollars.

Comment: Did the oxygen sensor resolve the problem?